# htaccess redirect from wordpress page to a php page

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have recently had to change a URL on a website (in PHP on Apache).

**The old URL is:** `http://content.mywebsite.org.uk/hidden/discounts/`
*When a user visits the above link.*
**The new URL is:** `http://www.mywebsite.org.uk/charity_benefits.php`

I have tried variants of the following (and some others), but its just not working for me.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/hidden/discounts/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/hidden/discounts/$ /charity_benefits.php [R=302,L,NC]
```

I need the redirect to redirect to **`www`** mywebsite.org.uk. (Notice the `www`! Its important!).

So basically, a simple redirect from the old page to the new page. (Which are on different subdomains (OLD: `content.`, NEW: `www.`) which are hosted on the same server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, Figured out the issue, posting it as the answer incase someone else has this simple issue.
Basically, I had 2 subdomains `content.` and `www.`
It turns out I was editing the wrong `.htaccess` file!

I needed to add the rewrite rule to the `.htaccess` which is hosted on `content.`
I was trying to add it to the `.htaccess` hosted on `www.`.

So obviously it didnt work.

So if your redirects are not working (and your using multiple subdomains to point to different 
folders)...

**MAKE SURE YOUR EDITING THE RIGHT `.htaccess` FILE!**

(*why do dumb things like this always happen to me!*)

Comment: It says I have to wait 2 days.. I will... in 2 days..